# RxJS - Skip functions if some condition is met

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In an Angular Web-Application I am working on, I need to do a lot of things using `Observable`s.
Usually `Observable`s are used for sequences of asynchronous events, however, for me, it is usually only 1 result (coming from a http-request).
I often need to do some complex mapping to get the desired result out of the http-requests. However, this mapping is only needed, if some condition is met, else I could skip the whole mapping part and return a default value.
For example:
I want to get the sum of the sales of a specific `article` in a given `city`.
Following steps are required to get the result:

1. Get all `client`s, which live in that given `city`
   city.getClients() : `Observable<Array<Client>>`
   (`http GET` -> `Observable<Array<Client>>`)
2. Determine the sales of the given `article` for every `client`
   (`flatMap` -> `Observable<Array<ClientSale>>`)
3. Get the total amount of sales of the given `article` for every `client`.
   (`map` -> `Observable<Array<number>>`)
4. Sum it up
   (`map` -> `Observable<number>`)

Now it is possible, that there are no `client`s living in that given city.
In that case, steps 2-4 could be skipped and the `onNext`-callback could be called with the value `0`.

Note, that this is just a simple example, to explain what I want to do. The real use-cases require more steps and I would need to do a

```
if (meetsCondition(x))
    return map(x);
else
    return defaultValue;
```

in every step.

The `filter`-function is almost what I am looking for. However it does not call the `onNext` for the filtered values.

Is  there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

**EDIT:**
I'll try to add some more detail to the question:
I have a lot of lazy-loaded data in my application. So if you request a `city`, it won't load the related `client`s until you request them by calling `getClients`.
Therefore most of the `getter`s return an `Observable` of the data instead of the data itself.

Now I often need to calculate things, by combining values of different sources (`client`, `article` etc.).
Often this calculation could be stoped in the middle, as no valid result could be determined.
This could be the case, if a value is empty, but also if a filtered list contains more then one entry.

So the perfect solution for me would be, if I am able to do something like this:

```
client.getOrders()
   .skipIf(value => !meetsCondition(value), defaultValue)
   .map(value => mapValue(value))        // Probably not called
   .map(value => mapValueAgain(value))   // Probably not called
   .subscribe(value => {
        if (value == defaultValue)
            console.log("Skip");
        else
            console.log(value)
   });
```

Comment: Did you look at `Rx.Observable.if`? It may satisfy your need.

Comment: But I would need to use the `if` for every step right? Also if i need to execute a `flatMap` (or any other RXJS operator) if condition is met, I wouldn't be able to do that right?

Comment: Have you tried to give callback as a parameter into `getClients` method? With this way, if your result is empty, you can call `emptyCallback`, and if not you can call whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is, that this "filter" does not always apply for empty values. Sometimes I need to "filter", if not exactly one entry is in a determined list. Also the `getClients` is a general getter method, returning a lazy loaded list of clients, so I don't want to add a paramter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I constructed your case like the following. Right?

```
function getClients(city:string) {
    return Observable.of(city == 'Seoul' ? ['c1', 'c2'] : []).delay(100);
}
function getSales(client:string, article:string) {
    let sales:any = {
        'c1': {
            'item1': 10,
            'item2': 20
        },
        'c2': {
            'item1': 30,
            'item2': 40
        }
    };

    return Observable.of(sales[client][article]).delay(100);
}

let city = 'Seoul';
let article = 'item2';

getClients(city)
    .mergeMap(clients => {
        console.log('>> mergeMap');
        let salesObs = clients.map<Observable<number>>(client => getSales(client, article));
        return Observable.merge(salesObs).mergeAll();
    })
    .reduce((sum, sales) => {
        console.log('>> reduce');
        return sum + sales;
    }, 0)
    .subscribe(value => console.log(`sum = ${value}`));
```

No problems though clients is empty in this case. Change city to another value and try.

I added some codes to work in general conditions using 'map' and 'catch'.
If it meets some skip condition, 'mergeMap' and 'reduce' is not excuted.

```
getClients(city)
    .map(clients => {
        // some skip condition
        if (clients.length == 0)
            throw 0 /* default value */;

        return clients;
    })
    .mergeMap(clients => {
        console.log('>> mergeMap');
        let salesObs = clients.map<Observable<number>>(client => getSales(client, article));
        return Observable.merge(salesObs).mergeAll();
    })
    .reduce((sum, sales) => {
        console.log('>> reduce');
        return sum + sales;
    }, 0)
    .catch((err, caught) => {
        console.log('>> catch');
        // default value
        return Observable.of(err);
    })
    .subscribe(value => console.log(`sum = ${value}`));
```

Comment: So basicly "throw" does exactly what I need? And I can `catch` it at a given point and from there execution will continue?

Comment: `catch` return Observable not value. So you can excute something you want. Refer [official documentation for catch](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch)

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try to and let you know about the results!

Comment: I just tryed it and it seems to work fine. I can now add a `throw`, whenever I want to skip certain executions and add a `catch`, whenever I want the skipped values to reenter my sequence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't this method forfeit error handling? What if there's an actual error, such as if you need to do some network request before the `catch` operator, and that request fails?

Comment: @ChristianJensen you could create a special Error for that case, something like `throw new SkipError()` and then only catch this kind of error and rethrow all others

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Rxjs [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif) operator.